Display memory layout in rust
Is there macro to debug what happened in memory layout in rust? Or do I actually should use debug features in vscode or another IDE? What is the best practice to debugging memory with looking current value and its address in a variable in rust?
Given simple code like this:
fn main(){
    let my_int: u8 = 2;
    let my_float: f32 = 2.4;
    let my_bool: bool = true;
    
    show_memory_layout!(&my_int, &my_float, &my_bool);
}

Expecting output like this:
Address | Value   |   Type  | Var_Name   | Location
0x1000  |  0x02   |    u8   | my_int     |  Stack
...
0x2000  |  0x40   |   f32   | 0_my_float |  Stack
0x2001  |  0x19   |   f32   | 1_my_float |  Stack
0x2002  |  0x99   |   f32   | 2_my_float |  Stack
0x2003  |  0x9a   |   f32   | 3_my_float |  Stack
...
0x3000  |  0x01   |   bool  | my_bool    |  Stack

Or another memory display utilities like this:
show_memory!(src_ptr, dst_ptr);
// src_ptr is 0x1000, dst_ptr is 0x2000

Will display same columns like above but just address and value, and with specified range:
Address | Value
0x1000  |  0x00
0x1001  |  0x69
...
0x2000  |  0x69

No need exactly what I expect, I'm just expecting similar feature like that.

dbg!, type_name and {:p} will give you most parts of what you want, I don't know if the differentiation between Stack, Heap, … is even possible in general. But typically that's all info a debugger will show you.

Safe memory access:
#![allow(unused)]

use mem_viewer::*;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Container<T>{
    v: T
}

fn type_of<T>(_: T) -> &'static str {
    std::any::type_name::<T>()
}

macro_rules! safe_view_mem  {
    ($var: expr) => {
        let name = stringify!($var);
        let type_name = type_of($var);
        let addr = $var as *const _ as *const u8 as usize;
        let size = std::mem::size_of_val($var);

        // Print metadata
        println!("Name: {}", name);
        println!("Type: {}", type_name);
        println!("Addr: {:016x}", addr);
        println!("Size: {}", size);

        let mut container: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        bincode::serialize_into(&mut container, &Container { v: $var }).unwrap();
        println!("Container Raw : {:?}", container);
        if container.len() != size { // If not same, then there is metadata of serializer with 8 bytes.
            container = (&container[8..]).to_vec();
        }
        println!("Container     : {:?}", container);
        let container = container;

        println!("Container Len : {}", container.len());
        println!("Container Addr: {:016x}", container.as_ptr() as usize);

        println!("     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII");
        println!("------------------------------------------------");
        // Iterate over Vec<u8>
        for (i, byte) in container.iter().enumerate() {
            let addr = byte as *const u8 as usize;
            let hex = format!("{:02x}", byte);
            let dec = format!("{:03}", byte);
            let bin = format!("{:08b}", byte);
            let ascii = if byte.is_ascii_graphic() {
                format!("{}  ", *byte as char)
            } else {
                match byte {
                            0   => "NUL",
                            1   => "SOH",
                            2   => "STX",
                            3   => "ETX",
                            4   => "EOT",
                            5   => "ENQ",
                            6   => "ACK",
                            7   => "BEL",
                            8   => "BS ",
                            9   => "HT ",
                            10  => "LF ",
                            11  => "VT ",
                            12  => "FF ",
                            13  => "CR ",
                            14  => "SO ",
                            15  => "SI ",
                            16  => "DLE",
                            17  => "DC1",
                            18  => "DC2",
                            19  => "DC3",
                            20  => "DC4",
                            21  => "NAK",
                            22  => "SYN",
                            23  => "ETB",
                            24  => "CAN",
                            25  => "EM ",
                            26  => "SUB",
                            27  => "ESC",
                            28  => "FS ",
                            29  => "GS ",
                            30  => "RS ",
                            31  => "US ",
                            32  => "SPC",
                            127 => "DEL",
                            _   => "UNK",
                    }.to_string()
            };
            println!("{:016x} | {}  | {} | {} | {}", addr, hex, dec, bin, ascii);
        };
        println!();
        }
    }


fn main(){
    let my_str = "A B C";
    let my_u16: u16 = 69;
    let my_f32: f32 = 3.14; // 0x4048f5c3 according IEEE 754
    let my_vec: Vec<u16> = vec![69, 70, 71];
    let my_vec_of_box: Vec<Box<u8>> = vec![Box::new(69u8), Box::new(70), Box::new(71)];

    safe_view_mem!(my_str);
    //safe_view_mem!(*my_str); // expected &{unknown}, found str
    safe_view_mem!(&my_u16);
    safe_view_mem!(&my_f32);
    safe_view_mem!(&my_vec);
    //safe_view_mem!(*my_vec); // expected &{unknown}, found [u16]
    safe_view_mem!(&my_vec_of_box);

    println!("########## ABOVE IS SAFE, BELOW IS UNSAFE #############\n");

    view_mem!(my_str);
    view_mem!(*my_str);
    view_mem!(my_u16);
    view_mem!(my_f32);
    view_mem!(my_vec);
    view_mem!(*my_vec);
    view_mem!(my_vec_of_box);
}

Output:
Type: &str
Addr: 00007ff79a494df0
Size: 5
Container Raw : [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 32, 66, 32, 67]
Container     : [65, 32, 66, 32, 67]
Container Len : 5
Container Addr: 000002b90ba05fa0
     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII
------------------------------------------------
000002b90ba05fa0 | 41  | 065 | 01000001 | A  
000002b90ba05fa1 | 20  | 032 | 00100000 | SPC
000002b90ba05fa2 | 42  | 066 | 01000010 | B  
000002b90ba05fa3 | 20  | 032 | 00100000 | SPC
000002b90ba05fa4 | 43  | 067 | 01000011 | C  

Name: &my_u16
Type: &u16
Addr: 000000fc751fa022
Size: 2
Container Raw : [69, 0]
Container     : [69, 0]
Container Len : 2
Container Addr: 000002b90ba03480
     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII
------------------------------------------------
000002b90ba03480 | 45  | 069 | 01000101 | E  
000002b90ba03481 | 00  | 000 | 00000000 | NUL

Name: &my_f32
Type: &f32
Addr: 000000fc751fa024
Size: 4
Container Raw : [195, 245, 72, 64]
Container     : [195, 245, 72, 64]
Container Len : 4
Container Addr: 000002b90ba03500
     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII
------------------------------------------------
000002b90ba03500 | c3  | 195 | 11000011 | UNK
000002b90ba03501 | f5  | 245 | 11110101 | UNK
000002b90ba03502 | 48  | 072 | 01001000 | H
000002b90ba03503 | 40  | 064 | 01000000 | @

Name: &my_vec
Type: &alloc::vec::Vec<u16>
Addr: 000000fc751fa028
Size: 24
Container Raw : [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69, 0, 70, 0, 71, 0]
Container     : [69, 0, 70, 0, 71, 0]
Container Len : 6
Container Addr: 000002b90ba03470
     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII
------------------------------------------------
000002b90ba03470 | 45  | 069 | 01000101 | E
000002b90ba03471 | 00  | 000 | 00000000 | NUL
000002b90ba03472 | 46  | 070 | 01000110 | F
000002b90ba03473 | 00  | 000 | 00000000 | NUL
000002b90ba03474 | 47  | 071 | 01000111 | G
000002b90ba03475 | 00  | 000 | 00000000 | NUL

Name: &my_vec_of_box
Type: &alloc::vec::Vec<alloc::boxed::Box<u8>>
Addr: 000000fc751fa040
Size: 24
Container Raw : [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69, 70, 71]
Container     : [69, 70, 71]
Container Len : 3
Container Addr: 000002b90ba03580
     Address     | Hex | Dec |    Bin   | ASCII
------------------------------------------------
000002b90ba03580 | 45  | 069 | 01000101 | E
000002b90ba03581 | 46  | 070 | 01000110 | F
000002b90ba03582 | 47  | 071 | 01000111 | G

########## ABOVE IS SAFE, BELOW IS UNSAFE #############

Name: my_str
Type: &str
Size: 16 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0000fc751fa010 | 0xf0 | 240 | 0b11110000 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa011 | 0x4d | 077 | 0b01001101 |  M
 0x0000fc751fa012 | 0x49 | 073 | 0b01001001 |  I
 0x0000fc751fa013 | 0x9a | 154 | 0b10011010 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa014 | 0xf7 | 247 | 0b11110111 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa015 | 0x7f | 127 | 0b01111111 |  DEL
 0x0000fc751fa016 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa017 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa018 | 0x05 | 005 | 0b00000101 |  ENQ
 0x0000fc751fa019 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01a | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01b | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01c | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01d | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01e | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa01f | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL

Name: *my_str
Type: str
Size: 5 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x007ff79a494df0 | 0x41 | 065 | 0b01000001 |  A
 0x007ff79a494df1 | 0x20 | 032 | 0b00100000 |  SPC
 0x007ff79a494df2 | 0x42 | 066 | 0b01000010 |  B
 0x007ff79a494df3 | 0x20 | 032 | 0b00100000 |  SPC
 0x007ff79a494df4 | 0x43 | 067 | 0b01000011 |  C

Name: my_u16
Type: u16
Size: 2 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0000fc751fa022 | 0x45 | 069 | 0b01000101 |  E
 0x0000fc751fa023 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL

Name: my_f32
Type: f32
Size: 4 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0000fc751fa024 | 0xc3 | 195 | 0b11000011 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa025 | 0xf5 | 245 | 0b11110101 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa026 | 0x48 | 072 | 0b01001000 |  H
 0x0000fc751fa027 | 0x40 | 064 | 0b01000000 |  @

Name: my_vec
Type: alloc::vec::Vec<u16>
Size: 24 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0000fc751fa028 | 0x03 | 003 | 0b00000011 |  ETX
 0x0000fc751fa029 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02a | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02b | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02c | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02d | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02e | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa02f | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa030 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa031 | 0x5f | 095 | 0b01011111 |  _
 0x0000fc751fa032 | 0xa0 | 160 | 0b10100000 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa033 | 0x0b | 011 | 0b00001011 |  VT
 0x0000fc751fa034 | 0xb9 | 185 | 0b10111001 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa035 | 0x02 | 002 | 0b00000010 |  STX
 0x0000fc751fa036 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa037 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa038 | 0x03 | 003 | 0b00000011 |  ETX
 0x0000fc751fa039 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03a | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03b | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03c | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03d | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03e | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa03f | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL

Name: *my_vec
Type: [u16]
Size: 6 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0002b90ba05f00 | 0x45 | 069 | 0b01000101 |  E
 0x0002b90ba05f01 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0002b90ba05f02 | 0x46 | 070 | 0b01000110 |  F
 0x0002b90ba05f03 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0002b90ba05f04 | 0x47 | 071 | 0b01000111 |  G
 0x0002b90ba05f05 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL

Name: my_vec_of_box
Type: alloc::vec::Vec<alloc::boxed::Box<u8>>
Size: 24 bytes
      Address     | Hex  | Dec |    Bin     | ASCII
---------------------------------------------------
 0x0000fc751fa040 | 0x03 | 003 | 0b00000011 |  ETX
 0x0000fc751fa041 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa042 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa043 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa044 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa045 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa046 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa047 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa048 | 0x20 | 032 | 0b00100000 |  SPC
 0x0000fc751fa049 | 0x5a | 090 | 0b01011010 |  Z
 0x0000fc751fa04a | 0xa0 | 160 | 0b10100000 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa04b | 0x0b | 011 | 0b00001011 |  VT
 0x0000fc751fa04c | 0xb9 | 185 | 0b10111001 |  ...
 0x0000fc751fa04d | 0x02 | 002 | 0b00000010 |  STX
 0x0000fc751fa04e | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa04f | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa050 | 0x03 | 003 | 0b00000011 |  ETX
 0x0000fc751fa051 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa052 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa053 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa054 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa055 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa056 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL
 0x0000fc751fa057 | 0x00 | 000 | 0b00000000 |  NUL


Letting the user pass their own size is iffy at best since if they get it wrong and overshoot then you read past the object which is undefined behavior. And even when they do get it right, this isn't allowed for type with padding: reading that is also undefined behavior. So trying to read the bytes of an arbitrary type is unsound within Rust. A separate debugger does not have this gotcha.

Do you have a typo when printing the "Type"? You're just displaying the source expression again.

@kmdreko you are right there is rendundant code, at first my macro is supposed to accept one paramater which is variable only so it will become safely without tell user to specify the size. I need to edit it, separating meta of variable and printing function.

To rephrase: printing the type, address, and size is all well and good, but displaying the underlying bytes can't be done safely for an arbitrary value.

Here I published it https://crates.io/crates/mem_viewer, that was the best I can do. Maybe I need to optimize it later, like buffered print.

You have seemingly read past the most important part of my comments: your macro is unsound. It can cause undefined behavior without the end user employing unsafe which is against a core philosophy of Rust. Why have you ignored my warnings?

@kmdreko But people who use my macro is intended for debugging purpose, not production. So I think it will be fine.

"undefined behavior is fine for my purposes" - it really isn't. I don't think you understand the gravity of what I've been saying. And even if you are insistent on leaving it unsound and using it for your own purposes only in cases where you know it is safe (which I'm not confident you do), you've published it as a crate so that others may be unknowingly cause undefined behavior in their programs when they think everything is safe. That is negligent and almost disrespectful.

Okay, I've gotten upset and stopped being helpful, so lets reverse course... You can make this safe by getting your bytes via bytemuck::bytes_of since they've done the work of creating constraints to ensure it is safe. Your macro would fail to compile if it isn't ensured. Unfortunately this doesn't look implemented for &str. Maybe that can be proposed.

@kmdreko I have updated it, tell me if it's still unsafe.

You don't have any unsafe so it should be guaranteed to be safe in terms of memory safety. However, the bytes from bincode::serialize will not be true to what is actually at the displayed address for all but the most trivial examples. Your container.len() != size condition only "fixes" very specific cases.

Indeed, bincode::serialize is mainly for reading the content safely, opposite how unsafe reading with derefering var.  And yeah, the displayed address on table is the container address instead of true address of variable. I updated logic to len != size && len >=8

@kmdreko Thank you very much for your warning, I hope you understand I'm just a Rust beginner, I have realized Rust is so stricting about safety, realizing another unsafe dependency will make domino effect of another dependents. I was coming from high level language (ML dev) and low level language (embedded system), both of them never thought about safety in coding. Rust is great, I feel this language is high level and low level at same time.
